# Delete NoUIEntryPoints-DesignMode packages

Tags: debugging, uwp, file-extension

When uninstalling programs I see hundreds of packages with the name "NoUIEntryPoints-DesignMode".
As a result of my research I have recognized if you debug an UWP-App which registers a file extension it will create this package and the system is not able to delete it.

How can I delete them all?

At the moment the "Apps & Features"-Page looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the following PowerShell command:

`Get-AppxPackage -Publisher "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" | ? {$_.IsDevelopmentMode -eq "True"} | Remove-AppxPackage`

This does 3 steps:

1. Gets all installed AppX packages published by Microsoft.
2. Filters them by those marked as DevelopmentMode.
3. Removes the results.

I just wasted a bunch of time trying to figure out how to remove 1000+ "NoUIEntryPoints-DesignMode" debug application deploys as well so I thought I'd save other developers to annoyance.

**Note**: If you have just want to delete all developer mode apps, you can remove the -Publisher filtering:

`Get-AppxPackage | ? {$_.IsDevelopmentMode -eq "True"} | Remove-AppxPackage`

Comment: WARNING! Make sure you read the entire answer. I made the foolish mistake of copying that command, and it deletes WAY too much. The bottom command is what you should be running. Can I suggest updating the answer to reversing the order of those two commands?

Comment: Ignore my comment above, as the answer has now been updated.

Comment: I found changing the filter to ? {$_.IsDevelopmentMode -eq "True" -and $_.InstallLocation -like ""} seems to limit the results/removal to NoUIEntryPoints-DesignMode items only.