# Is it safe to uninstall all 'NoUiEntryPoints' "apps"?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

My "apps and features" (in Settings) has a couple of 'NoUiEntryPoints' "apps". And the start screen - many more.

Is it safe to delete them? I know [there is a question about how to remove them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519096/delete-nouientrypoints-designmode-packages). I'm asking if it really is safe to do that without checking first what they are. (How can that even be done?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to remove them. At one point these "apps" were generated whenever you used the Visual Studio Designer which used this approach to display the preview. This has been fixed since, but the "apps" will remain installed in your PC unless you uninstall them manually.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a official source, but there is a lot of threads discussing this, including this well accepted SO Q&A, so I think it is proven well by a large sample of develoeprs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519096/delete-nouientrypoints-designmode-packages/38556174#38556174

Comment: The info about this being a bug appeared in the build that fixed the problem as well - https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/11/08/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17035-pc/#CuGBpHEtHevCYFYs.97

Comment: Thanks. Especially for that second link.